# How to check if username exists in this data in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

We are trying to show online users. And check if the user is online then display the p tag in HTML. The point is that in the bellow code it shows all online users in console.log.

```
public isOnline: boolean = false;
...
...
    ngOnInit() {
        this.socket.emit('online', { room: 'global', user: this.user.username });
        this.socket.on('refreshPage', () => {
          this.GetUserData(this.name);
        });
      ...
      ...
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.socket.on('usersOnline', data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
```

Now above console.log displays in console the list of online users.
How can we check if that specific user is online or not?
by replacing console.log something like this:

```
this.isOnline = /* [write a logic check this.user.username exist in data ] */
```

And then adding p tag for each user like this:

```
<p class="" *ngIf="isOnline">online</p>
```

How can this code be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array.some with the condition which will return a boolean true/false

```
this.isOnline = data.some(d=>d.username == user.username);
```

Comment: It's not working. <p class="" *ngIf="isOnline">online</p> doesn't appear for that user.

Comment: When I change this.user.name above one it shows online but for all users even for those ones who are offline.

Comment: what if we use something like this:
 CheckIfOnline(name) {
    const result = _.indexOf(this.onlineusers, name);
    if (result > -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

How can it communicate with data with ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: I dont get your quesiton. can you see what does this.isOnline print?

Comment: when there was console.log(data) it printed the names of online users in the console. 
When I replace it with:   this.isOnline = data.some(d=>d.name === user.name); and add ng if in above html p tag it shows that p tag on the profiles who are offlines. So it means this function which you advised is not filtering.

Comment: that is online ng if is added on each profile of users. and it should be shown if that user is online. But for getting it fixed first should be console.log(data) replaced with something other.

Answer (score -1):

This code may be useful to you:

```
var data= ['Javid', 'David', 'Alex', 'john'];
const name= "Javid"
function search(data){
  return data.filter(item=>name=== item).length ? true: false;
}
console.log(search(data));
```

Comment: Please add a few words explaining why your code may be useful in order to improve your answer.